# UWP Access Violation Exception

Tags: c#, exception, nullpointerexception, uwp, access-violation

I get the following exception when i move items from a tab to another in an ObservableCollection that is bound to a pivot control in UWP.

**Exception thrown at 0x699C7165 (Windows.UI.Xaml.Phone.dll) in IRIS.ZustellerApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.**

I also managed to dig the dump and it seems the exception occurs at 
**Windows_UI_Xaml_Phone!XamlControlsTestHookCreateLoopingSelector**

It's interesting this doesn't respect the same pattern every time to reproduce.
I almost tried everything to fix this with no result.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this also happen when you run the app on the pc? I encountered a similar problem on the phone but not on the pc. I think this is a bug within Windows.UI.Xaml.Phone.dll because 0x00000000 is the address of a NULL pointer

Comment: Yes it happens in the emulator too.

Comment: Can you please share us a demo for testing? Or may be some code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is an old topic however I have recently dealt with a similar Access Violation problem and it was caused by attempting to remove a PivotItem with a call from a ContentDialog. Said dialog asked if the user wished to close the pivot and then the access violation occurred.
My guess is the ContentDialog runs on a different thread from the UIThread and therefore did not have the proper access to remove a UI component. Perhaps your code is not running on the UIThread too?

My 2 cents.

Comment: Thanks. Something similar was happening here too.

Comment: I received this when I simply typed something in a TextBox and pressed tab.

Comment: In my case, it was an overflow problem, but somehow the error was access violation. Fixing the overflow problem fixed the access violation exception